# Take data from query string and put into another form value (for both display and posting)

Tags: string, wordpress, forms

With that said, there is a question that seems to be asked a lot and has answers - but I'm not a programmer 'enough' to understand all the different explanations.  I was hoping for something more clear and concise to my very specific example and need.

I have two forms.  (I might also add this is being used on Wordpress)

One form is on the first page and will collect age, home value, and debt owed - all in drop down select fields.

The second form is on the next page and will collect other contact information and upon submit - will post all the fields to my CRM.

I have been able to successfully get the data from the first form into a query string on the page of the second form.  But try as I might - I just can't figure out how to get the field data from the query string into my field forms.  (Both display or pre-populated and as a value ready to be submitted once the rest of the fields are completed.)

Here is an actual query string:

```
http://example.com/2-form-test-2-of-2/?age=75&value=572%2C500&lien=107%2C500&sendbutton=#.UYSBEKKG2So
```

I simply need to get "age" - "value" and "lien" from that query string showing in the fields on the 2nd page.  Simple is best - even if it's 'hack-ish' as I will most likely just include the code directly on the Wordpress page that includes this form.

Comment: Can you post the code generating the second form?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to add a piece of javascript that gets fired on page load and:

```
1) disables form post button
2) populates form fields with values from URL
3) enables form post button
```

If these values are just suggestions for user, which he could easily change before posting — this should work.

If, on the other hand, these values are internal and unchangeable by user, you should not expose these in editable form and allow user to change those by editing URL or form posting (but including these as read-only page fragments is apparently ok).

Answer (score -1):

This is place for only programmers. To become a programmer, please refer some online resources and ebooks. without knowing basic concepts, you can't understand anything.

even after understanding basics, if you have doubts, you can ask here, providing the code samples you have developed.